# Race Face 2x Spider for Boost 64/104 BCD Bolts?

Tags: chainring, bolt

I am unable to find any info on what bolts I need to install the 104 and 64 BCD chainrings onto this spider. The spider doesn't ship with bolts and I cannot find any documentation anywhere(!)

https://www.treefortbikes.com/RaceFace-Cinch-Direct-Mount-2x-Spider-Boost-Wide-Chainline
https://www.modernbike.com/race-face-cinch-direct-mount-2x-spider-boost-64-104bcd---black
PN RaceFace F10017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CS:

I would order up part number A10006.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

--

Warranty and Service- Race Face/ Easton.
Service Support | RACE FACE

Comment: Can you describe what "part number A10006" comprises?

Comment: Chainring Bolt(8) & Nut(4) (TORX AL BLK )
Torx recesses
x4 long male screws
x4 male short screws
x4 female screw
Race Face M8x10(4) M8x8.5(4)/Nut M8x6.5(4) Alu Black